# Destructuring returning undefined variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying out the new destructuring feature of ES6, but having some trouble either understanding it, or getting it to work.

```
var test = {
    testme: "asd",
    funcA: function() {
       console.log("A");
   }
};
var [ testme, funcA ] = test;
console.log(testme);
console.log(funcA);
```

I expected to see in the console `"asd"` and `function() { ... }` but I get `undefined` for both.

Using Firefox 28.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you destructure an object you have to use the object's structure:

```
var {testme, funcA} = test;
```